# Is that possible to store the AWS IVS steam video data in to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using **Amazon Interactive Video Service(AWS IVS)** on my website to stream the **Zoom** meeting. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/what-is.html
To begin with is that possible to store the stream from IVS to AWS S3? I couldn't find in the document. It would be helpful if someone shares the documentation for this.